# Webapp2 and disappearing session after POST request

Tags: ajax, google-app-engine, session, webapp2

Appengine 1.7.4, webapp2, sessions.

Sessions are configured as shown in documentation: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html#webapp2_extras.sessions.SessionStore

```
# Some object
def post(self):
    logging.error(self.session.get('cart')) #A 1 item

    if '_put' in self.request.params:
        return self.put()

    cart = self.session.get('cart')
    # add one item to cart
    self.session['cart'] = cart

    logging.error(self.session.get('cart')) #B OK, 2 items
    return self.redirect(URL)

def put(self):
    logging.error(self.session.get('cart')) #C 1 item?!
    # some code
    return self.redirect(URL)
```

Two POST request send by AJAX.

```
First without _put
- #A - returns 1 item - OK.
- #B - returns 2 items - OK.

Second, POST with _put.
- #A - returns 1 item - why? session was changed?
- #C - as above
```

Requests are executed one by one (user clicks once, two requests). Any ideas why this might be happening?

If I run only the first request (without _put) and refresh page - session is saved correctly.

Problem started after the migration from the webapp (1.x) and Python 2.5.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How much time is between these two requests? Less then 1 or 2 seconds? Then you might have a race-condition here:

1. Req. 1 reads the session
2. Req. 2 reads the session
3. Req. 1 saves its session
4. Req. 2 saves its session

==> Changes from Req. 1 are lost. Please note that (due to the distributed architecture of the appengine) "saving" can occur even **after** the request itself has finished!